# Concatenate all files of type but specify some files to come first

Tags: bash, zsh

I want to recursively concatenate all the files of a type in a directory structure whilst specifying some files that should come first and some files that should come last.

For example, give I have the following file structure:

```
header.txt
interesting.txt
sadfsa.txt
oih.txt
nkli.txt
footer.txt
dir/lnln.txt
```

I would like to specify the concatenation as something like: `cat header.txt interesting.txt *.txt footer.txt`. But this, would include header.txt - and the other specified files - twice.

What would be the cleanest approach to do this be?

Comment: (1) What happens with a file in the directory, which is not in the list - say: `foo.txt`. Where should it be placed? (2) Why is this tagged _bash_  and _zsh_? Either be specific with the implementation language, or, if you don't care which language it is implemented in, because you are only searching for an algorithm, tag it with _algorithm_.

Comment: 1) Caught by the wild card, it would be included in the middle
2) Looking for an implementation in either (they are similar). Not looking for a generic algorithm.

Comment: They are different languages. You can ask a question for each, but one question for both is too broad for this website.

Comment: To (1): There is no wildcard in the example list you posted; that's why I asked. (2) Stackoverflow is no free programming service. You are supposed to either publish your own attempt, or turn to a web site which does support this kind of service.

Comment: 1) I specify `*.txt` in how I would think to approach this 2) that's bit harsh, I wouldn't expect that some someone who's contributed as much as me to this site.

Comment: @oguzismail yes & no. They are similarities. On MacOS, they are both available. Feel that would be wasting time.

Comment: Both shells support the same `ksh`-style negative wildcard (though requiring different options be enabled in each case): `cat header.txt interesting.txt !(header|footer|interesting).txt footer.txt`.

Comment: @Ross : If I would approach this problem, I would first put a marker somewhere in the master file (listing the order of the files), so that I know which 7 files come at the start, and which ones come at the end. The marker could of course be a wildcard expression. Then I would initialize an array with all those marker files (*.txt). Then I would go through all the files in the master file, up to the marker. During this, I would remove the processed files from the array. Then I would go through the array and process everything **except** those in the master file. Then I process the remainder.

Answer (score 2):

What about storing all these file names in the right order in a `bash` indexed array?

```
$ unset a
$ declare -a a=(header.txt interesting.txt sadfsa.txt oih.txt \
  nkli.txt dir/lnln.txt footer.txt)
$ echo "${a[@]}"
header.txt interesting.txt sadfsa.txt oih.txt nkli.txt dir/lnln.txt footer.txt
```

And then:

```
$ cat "${a[@]}" > cat.txt
```

If the intermediate files are all `*.txt` files under the current directory, except the 3 special ones, you could use `find` to list them:

```
$ unset a
$ declare -a a=(header.txt interesting.txt)
$ a+=($(find . -type f ! -name header.txt ! -name interesting.txt ! -name footer.txt -name '*.txt'))
$ a+=(footer.txt)
$ echo "${a[@]}"
header.txt interesting.txt sadfsa.txt oih.txt nkli.txt dir/lnln.txt footer.txt
```

Finally, if your `bash` is recent enough (under macOS first install a decently recent one with macports or Homebrew), you can use the `extglob` option. We assume here that the 3 special files are in the current directory, that there are other `txt` files in the current directory and in subdirectories:

```
$ shopt -s extglob
$ echo header.txt interesting.txt !(footer|header|interesting).txt **/*.txt footer.txt
header.txt interesting.txt nkli.txt oih.txt sadfsa.txt dir/lnln.txt footer.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to use `awk`:

```sh
$ files=$(printf "%s\n" header.txt interesting.txt **/*.txt | awk "!visited[$0]++")
$ cat $files > output.txt
```

Explanation:

- `printf "%s\n" header.txt interesting.txt **/*.txt` prints all txt files plus the "special" ones each on a separate line. Also works recursively in Bash 4 or newer if you add `shopt -s globstar`.
- `awk "!visited[$0]++"` removes all duplicates. Normally, one could simply use `uniq`, but sadly that works only for duplicate lines that directly follow each other.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you know which files you would like to merge first,

1. Merge the two files `header.txt`and `interesting.txt` with the file you would like to merge with, and have the filenames recorded in an array.
2. Create a foreach loop, to loop through the files in the directory to be merged, and use an if statement inside the loop, to check if the filename is `header.txt` or `interesting.txt` and to continue to the next filename if it is.

Answer (score 0):

You could somehow exclude files from the pattern.
One option is to use the caret (^)

```
cat filewanted1st.txt filewanted2nd.txt *[^td].txt
```

This way you exclude files which end in a 't' or 'd' before .txt

Unfortunately, this would exclude some other files like filewanted3rd.txt as well (as it ends in a 'd').
So... I don't know better. Maybe someone will know how to use better excluding patterns inside a glob like this.

To find files in subdirectories too, use `shopt -s globstar` and`**/*` instead of `*`:

```
shopt -s globstar
cat filewanted1st.txt filewanted2nd.txt **/*[^td].txt
```

Comment: Also, above command prints the output to the console, redirect it as you need